# Prestahsop Import csv file

Tags: csv, import, prestashop, categories

I have a CSV File that contains categories. I'm trying to import it in prestashop but in vain, I keep getting this error:

`category->name is empty`

I'm using the same file in other website and it was imported correctly.

Comment: Try to check if the "name" column is selected in the import table.

Comment: thanks for your reply yes i was checked the table import and csv file has same name

Comment: Thank's finally i found best solution juste i change php version of my local server